# Testing that a generated batch of names are legally possible

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to get into the habit of unit testing my code. I am playing around trying to get a better grasp of what it can do. By default my method generates a random list of 30 product names.

The names are randomly chosen from two list:

> ```
> _adjectives = ['Awesome', 'Shiny', 'Impressive', 'Portable', 'Improved', 'Giant',
>                'Rocket-Powered', 'Super', 'Exploding', 'Invisible']
>
> _nouns = ['Anvil', 'Catapult' 'Disguise' 'Mousetrap', 'Hitch-Hiker Thumb',
>           'Roller Skates', 'Roller Skis', 'Packing Machine', 'Leg Muscle Vitamins',
>           'Camouflage', 'Golf Balls', 'Toaster', 'Grenade', 'Aspirin',
>           'Matches', 'Street Cleaner Wagons', 'Nitroglycerin', 'Bird Seeds',
>           'Glue', 'Smoke Bomb', 'Grease']
> ```

the resulting names looks like : ["Awesome Anvil", "Super Disguise", "Invisible Hitch-Hiker Thumb",..., "Exploding Golf Balls"]

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks that the generated names for a default batch of products are all valid possible names to generate (adjective, space, noun, from the lists of possible words)

My current thought is to use string processing to strip out each word using string processing then use `assertIn` from `unittest` to get the excepted answer but I'm honestly just stumped and only get half of what I expect. I'm trying to see a few examples on how this could be done I can weave into other examples  in the future.

Comment: In order to unit test something you should know the ***expected*** result. Then your test would compare the ***actual*** result with your expected. The first test you could do is to check that you are not returning an empty list for non-zero parameter..

Comment: I;m sorry I was working through several files for this. I ended up missing something I gave a more simplistic overview of the question that makes more sense.

Comment: Split the return on space and do two separate 'in` assertions.